# LABjs loading error

Tags: javascript, loader, labjs

I wrote a page loading almost all JS using labJS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lab.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $LAB
    .script({ src:"http://vk.com/js/api/share.js?90", type:"text/javascript", charset:"windows-1251" })
    .script("js/mootools.js").wait()
    .script("js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js").wait()
    .script("js/scroll.js")
    .wait(function(){
        addEvent();
        bind();
    })
    ;
</script>
```

If I browse it locally, with Usbwebserver, all works fine but when I load it on the webserver it doesn't work.
The debug console tells me "ReferenceError: $LAB is not defined" and all following calls to JS functions fail consequently.
I wonder whether the second script is executed before labJS was fully loaded but I don't understand why and how to solve it...

Comment: Check your browser network tab. Most likely problem is that you haven't really made the file available on your server, for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, after some more debug I found what was the problem.
I wrote lab.min.js while the filename was LAB.min.js.
My local server under windows is not case sensitive while the webserver is...